# Haar measure on $G \times G$, where $G$ is compact

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $G$ be a compact group. Let $\mu'$ and $\mu$ be the Haar measure on $G \times G$
and $G$, respectively, and further such that $\mu'(G \times G) = 1$ and $\mu(G)=1$.
Does it follow that $\mu' = \mu \times \mu$? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume that the borel sigma algebra on $G\times G$ is the same as the product of the Borel sigma algebras each on G (i.e $\mathcal{B}(G\times G)=\mathcal{B}(G)\times\mathcal{B}(G)$) then by uniqueness of Haar measure we have: $\mu'=c\mu\times\mu$ and evaluating on $G\times G$ we find $c=1$. If not then they cannot be equal as they are measures on different $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: Do you happen to know what kind of condition would imply $\mathcal{B}(G\times G)=\mathcal{B}(G)\times\mathcal{B}(G)$ by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: This may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84823/do-these-sigma-algebras-on-second-countable-spaces-coincide

Comment: For $B(G)\times B(G) \neq B(G\times G)$, we have the following picture: $\mu^{'}|_{B(G)\times B(G)}=\mu\times \mu$ and $\mu\times \mu$ admits a unique $G\times G$ invariant extension from the $\sigma$ algebra $B(G)\times B(G)$ to the $\sigma$-algebra$B(G\times G)$.